# Not able to add datepicker to new element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm dynamically adding new form elements using jquery. For some reason, a call to `.datepicker()` won't work on the new elements I add, but did work on the old ones that were not added dynamically. If I put `.attr('style', 'color: red;')`
instead of `.datepicker()`, it works. Note that the original call inside of the document ready function works.

This is the code that gets called when the add button is clicked:

```
function addMulti(name) {
    it = $('[name=' + name + ']');
    base = it.data('baseName');
    on = it.data('number') + 1;
    name = base + "-" + on;
    copy = it.clone()
    copy.prop("name", name).attr("data-is-default", false).removeAttr('data-number').
        fadeIn('slow').appendTo(it.parent());
    it.data('number', on); 
    if(it.hasClass('date-pickable')) { // <-- This returns true, I checked.
        copy.datepicker();
    // Where if I add clone.attr('style', 'color: red;') it turns it red.
}
}
```

This is the call that makes all of the fields that are created at that point date pickers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input.date-pickable").datepicker()
});
</script>
```

There are no errors that show up in firebug or the google chrome "inspect element" thing. Something odd is happening though. If I type in the same call as in the document.ready function into the firebug consul, it still won't make the newly added elements datepickers. Yet if I hover over the output, it selects the elements that it should be targeting.

```
$("input.date-pickable").datepicker() // What I typed in

Object[input#dp1371953134342.field-input 06/22/2013, input#dp1371953134343.field-input, input#dp1371953134342.field-input 06/22/2013, input#dp1371953134342.field-input 06/22/2013] // What it put out. The last three numbers are the IDs JQuery assigned to the added elements. I checked.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery UI's datepicker will always add the class `hasDatepicker` to any element that has a datepicker to avoid attaching multiple datepickers to the same element.
When you're cloning an element that already has a datepicker, you get that class as well, and you can't attach a new datepicker to the clone, as jQuery UI thinks the element already has a datepicker.

Remove the class from the clone:

```
var copy = it.clone(false);

copy.removeClass('hasDatepicker').prop("name", name)
    .attr("data-is-default", "false").removeAttr('data-number')
    .fadeIn('slow').appendTo(it.parent());
```

and try not to make all your variables global.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('focus',"input.date-pickable", function(){
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
});
</script>
```

[Demo JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e7h8n/)